# 'Resetting' Google Play Games Services so app forgets it previously connected (so it shows confirmation screen again)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

When I first integrated Google Play Games Services into my app, it came up with a 'confirmation screen', something like:

***App Name* wants to connect to Google Play Game Services**

I don't recall the exact wording.

While Alpha testing my app, one of my users has discovered a potential issue where he presses 'cancel' at that point instead of connecting. I would like to try to resolve this issue, but I can't recreate it because I can't work out how I can get that confirmation screen again!

I have implemented a 'log out' button in my app and that works, but when subsequently connecting, it just goes ahead without displaying the confirmation screen again.  Any ideas how I can force that screen to show again for testing?!

Comment: Just a side note, but worth doing: you can add an option somewhere in your UI so that player can connect/disconnect from Google Play Services (there are API calls for that). It is useful for testing as well as changing profiles from the game instead. Also if they cancel, they can easily sign-in later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps to "deauthorize" an app with G+ sign-in:

1. Open the `Google Settings` app on your device.
2. Next select the `Connected apps` option.
3. Find your app in the list and select it.
4. Finally click the `Disconnect` button.

A confirmation/warning will be displayed. Note that it says it can take up to an hour for the process to be completed.

After doing this your next sign-in attempt should re-request access for G+ sign-in.

Edit (screenshot of Google Settings):

[image: Google Settings]

Comment: Hey @free3dom - thanks, but I can't find a 'Connected Apps' section within my settings, is it under a subsection somewhere?  I'm runnin KitKat 4.4.4 on a Google Nexus 10 tablet if it makes any difference.  Thanks!

Comment: Check my edit, for me the `Connected apps` option is right at the top in the `Google Settings` app. I'm also running KK 4.4.4 but on a Nexus 4. I've had it there for a while now (not sure exactly how long).

Comment: This appears to no longer work @free3dom - any ideas?  New Question here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659572/android-cannot-disconnect-apps-correcty-from-google

Comment: In Android 8, I found it under Settings -> Google (Services & Preferences) -> Connected apps -> [App Name]